# Cosa significa "stare sotto a qualcuno" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L'andata* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Negus senza guardarlo gli disse: – Piantala, Bimbo, d’avercela con Morgan. Se **gli sto sotto io, puoi stargli sotto** anche tu. Farai bene a non far piú lo spiritoso con Morgan. Lui ha ventidue anni ed è un uomo, e tu sei un marmocchio di quindici, anche se come partigiano sei abbastanza anziano. 
>         Bimbo scrollò le spalle e disse: – Io ci patisco a vedere uno come Morgan comandare a dei tipi come noi. Non è che Morgan sia fesso, siamo noi che siamo troppo in gamba per lui. **Io gli sto sotto perché vedo te che gli stai sotto**. Ma non so se ci resisto ancora.

Non capisco il significato della locuzione "stare sotto a qualcuno" (in questo caso a Morgan) in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "sotto" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato espressioni come "stare sotto il sole" o "stare sotto la pioggia", ma non sono riuscita a vedere niente che abbia senso nel contesto del brano. Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire? Significa forse ubbidire le ordini di questa persona?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La tua interpretazione è secondo me corretta; qui *"stare sotto"* è utilizzato nel senso di "essere sottomesso" o "essere subalterno" alla persona di cui si sta parlando, di riconoscerne l'autorità.

Cfr. anche il sostantivo [sottoposto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sottoposto/).

Comment: È senz’altro corretta, visto che Morgan è il capo della formazione partigiana di cui fanno parte anche Negus e Bimbo.

Comment: ”Stare sotto a qualcuno” può anche significare “controllarlo da vicino, magari stimolandolo”. Non in questo caso, direi.